# WP8 Pivot Fast swapping Issue

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a pivot element with 3 pivots. Each pivot has a listbox item binded with a class object.
The data binding is coming from a Http resonse.
I have just one common function for all the pivotsitems loading.

When I swipe normally, the pivot behaves normally.
But now when I swipe very fast between the pages, the data gets mixed up for pivot items first(i.e data of previous ivot gets displayed) and after some time only the correct data is displayed.

Can you guide me as to is there any swipe event handler associaated with the pivot item. Or how should i handle this issue.

The following is the selection changed func:

```
private void RequestsPivot_LoadingPivotItem(object sender, PivotItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item == Unapproved_PivotItem)
            {
                status = RequestorStatus.UnApproved;
            }
            else if (e.Item == Rejected_PivotItem)
            {
                status = RequestorStatus.Rejected;
            }
            else if (e.Item == Approved_PivotItem)
            {
                status = RequestorStatus.Approved;
            }

            fetchData();
        }
```

Basically I want to clear the list of a pivotItem before it gets loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to load 4 pivot items in the order 4,1,2,3. Inside pivot selection changed event, for a right swipe you can delete the right-most item and add a item on the left, vice-versa. This way you can balance the items in the pivot.

Comment: You mean to say that I should add the pivot items dynamically to the pivot and not in the .xaml?